# How to change the color of just a div?

Tags: javascript, html

This code works, but how can I make it so that only a div changes color as oppose to the entire body?

```js
var color = function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

setInterval(function() { 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color(); //() to execute the function!
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  width: full;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor = color()`. Check out [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) and the various other methods of querying the DOM.

Comment: Sorry, I know the HTML is kind of skimpy, that's just the program I was using.

Comment: @MikeC has the correct answer https://jsfiddle.net/47hzseok/

Answer (score 3):

You need to be able to query the DOM for the correct element. A very simple way of doing this would be to use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which uses CSS selector style syntax to find elements in the DOM. Using that, your code would look like this.

```js
var color = function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

setInterval(function() { 
    document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor = color(); //() to execute the function!
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  width: full;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But that's just one way of querying the DOM. You could use [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) which retrieves a collection of every element with the matching tag.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
// Change the first one
divs[0].style.backgroundColor = color();
```

You could also give the `div` an ID and use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
<div id="coloredDiv"></div>
```

--

```
document.getElementById('coloredDiv').style.backgroundColor = color();
```

There are numerous ways of querying the DOM, just use the one that works best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an id to div and set it's color by accessing it by getElementById

```js
<script>
  var color = function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

setInterval(function() { 
    document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = color(); //() to execute the function!
}, 1000);
  </script>
```

```css
div {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  width: full;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body
```